# "Align with the requirements of the role of an attorney" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> These qualities and skills align with the requirements of the role of an attorney

Is this sentence correct?
I'm having doubts because of the repetition of "of"

Answer (score 1):

> These qualities and skills align with the requirements of the role of
> an attorney

Yes it is perfectly correct.

You could perhaps say, *These qualities and skills align with the requirements of an attorney's role*  However I prefer your version - it is both more formal and easier to understand..